# XSLT How to select node attribute value with xsl:for-each and xsl:if

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt, xsl-fo, xsl-variable

I have an XML file to render with XSLT 1.0.

My cas is the following :

> **If value of `longName` is *"Oui_Combi"***
>
> > **`$Publication` = `prodDate`** value (*21.11.2018*)
>
> **else**
>
> > **`$Publication` = `productionDates`** value (*17.11.2018, 21.11.2018*)

I'm not sur my syntax is correct on the for-each and/or on the xsl-if

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Manuscript dateAndTime="2018-11-16T10:20:59.177+01:00" renderEPS="" forMediation="false">
    <Order>
        <OrderHeader productionDates="17.11.2018, 21.11.2018">
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            <Criterion name="TypePublicity" ordering="1">
                TypePubOccasionnel <ValueParameter longName="Occasionnel"/>
            </Criterion>
            <Criterion name="JuraCombi" ordering="2">
                Oui_Combi <ValueParameter longName="Oui_Combi"/>
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            </Criterion>
        </OrderHeader>
        <FirstIssueData prodDate="21.11.2018"></FirstIssueData>
    </Order>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</Manuscript>
```

XSL part where I create my variable :

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Order/OrderHeader/Criterion">
    <xsl:if test="@name = 'JuraCombi'">

        <xsl:if test="ValueParameter/@longName = 'Oui_Combi'">
            <xsl:variable name="JuraCombi">
                OUI
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Publication">
                <xsl:value-of select="/Order/FirstIssueData/@prodDate" />
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="ValueParameter/@longName != 'Oui_Combi'">
            <xsl:variable name="JuraCombi">
                NON
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Publication">
                <xsl:value-of select="/Order/OrderHeader/@productionDates" />
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

...
```

The XSL part where I want to print my variable `$Publication` :

```
<xsl:template match="OrderHeader">
    <fo:table 
        table-layout="fixed" 
        width="18cm" 
        font-size="10pt" 
        padding="1.0pt">
        <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="60mm"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="60mm"/>
        <fo:table-body>

            ...

            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block padding="0.5cm">
                        Parutions
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3">
                    <fo:block padding="0.5cm">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$Publication" />
                    </fo:block>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>

            ...

        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

Maybe we can achieve it without for-each?

Not any online XSLT tool/checker can get me the detailled error but the rendering stops!

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of an XSLT variable is limited to the element that contains the `xsl:variable` and it applies only to expressions that occur after the `xsl:variable`. I.e., "the binding is visible for all following siblings and their descendants" as it says in the XSLT 1.0 spec (see https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#local-variables).

So your variables are out of scope outside of the `xsl:if` in which they are declared.

The thing to do is to turn your logic inside-out and put the conditional logic inside each `xsl:variable` element.  Something like (untested):

```
<xsl:variable name="JuraCombi">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ValueParameter/@longName = 'Oui_Combi'">OUI</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>NON</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Publication">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ValueParameter/@longName = 'Oui_Combi'">
      <xsl:value-of select="/Manuscript/Order/FirstIssueData/@prodDate" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="../@productionDates" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Note that your XPath to select `@prodDate` would not select anything. It needs the `/Manuscript` step because `Manuscript` is the document element.

It's not clear how your code for declaring the variables relates to the template that creates the `fo:table`.  For the variable values to be able to apply, you'd need to have the `xsl:apply-templates` that selects `OrderHeader` to be within the scope of the variables' declarations, and you'd need to pass the variables' values to the template using `xsl:with-param` and `xsl:param`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Passing-Parameters-to-Templates.

---

I'm not sure that I know what you mean in your comment, so this is the best solution that I can intuit:

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
  <xsl:variable name="JuraCombi">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="OrderHeader/Criterion[@name = 'JuraCombi']/ValueParameter/@longName = 'Oui_Combi'">OUI</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>NON</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="Publication">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$JuraCombi = 'OUI'">
        <xsl:value-of select="FirstIssueData/@prodDate" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="OrderHeader/@productionDates" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <fo:table 
      table-layout="fixed" 
      width="18cm" 
      font-size="10pt" 
      padding="1.0pt">
    <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="60mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="60mm"/>
    <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block padding="0.5cm">
            Parutions
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3">
          <fo:block padding="0.5cm">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$Publication" />
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, my first problem is actually to select the proper value if second /Criterion/ node. How to get it? Or the for-each and the first if are correct according to you ?

Comment: Thansk for your edit. It works in `match="Order"` scope, so now Il will make some tests to be in `match="OrderHeader"`. Thanks